# How to distinction between new and old added items (+ colorblind)?

Tags: lists, color-blindness

In my app the waiter can "open a table" and check what has been ordered or add new plates to the order.

The added items or the ordered ones are in the same list and for now i was showing the distinction between the two by coloring the "turn" box with blue while the ordered items has that box in greyish.

[image]

But some users has claimed that is hard to understand what has been newly added and even the colorblind people just can't distinct it at all.

What would be the best approach to discting the two type of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color is not the only visual contrast, try the others to use individually or in combination:

### Shape contrast

[image: shape]

### Size contrast

[image: Size]

### Weight contrast

[image: Weight]

### Figure/ground contrast

[image: Figure/ground]

### Texture contrast

[image: texture]

### Style contrast

[image: style]

### Position contrast

[image: Position]